# How to update the tableViewCell height after fetching the image?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

Disclaimer: There are multiple answers on StackOverflow regarding this but none of them seem to resolve the issue (Let me know If I missed some answer).

I have a table view and within it a tableView cell with three elements:

- Title
- Subtitle
- ImageView

All are dynamic (received from server) the only problem is that the height of all the images differs.

Added a logic to update the image view height constraint depending on the image height this is the logic used.
I have added this code in the UITableViewCell

```
let ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height
let newHeight = imageView.frame.width / ratio
imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = newHeight
layoutIfNeeded()
```

Though it resizes the image sometimes it shows the improper height for the cell (Attached image below).
Sometimes the imageView height increases while the image remains small (AspectFit)

I am setting the imageView.image to nil in the prepareForReuse.

Please let me know what is going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to prefetch the size of image from server - return it's size as a number and preallocate space for it in `UITableView`.

Otherwise you have to reload each cell that will load an image after loading it from server and that will force reculculation of whole layout for entire `UITableView` - which is quite heavy operation. Especially assuming you will load several images, recalculating layout for each will affect performance of your application a lot.

The way `UITableView` works is that it precalculates a position for each cell (x,y coordinates) at the start - position of each Cell depends on position and size of previous cells. Then it keeps it cached and uses to optimise the speed of scrolling and reusing of elements inside it.
If you load an image for first cell at the top - it will affect all other cells below it - and it will have to recalculate it. Which in your case will happen for each image loaded.

Comment: Ya actually that's the last thing i have in my mind but as it involves server side to calculate image height and send it so thought of getting others views and opinion.